# How to get the customer info of the customer with the highest number of transactions

Tags: sql, oracle, rdbms

I have an oracle sql database consisting of three tables and I was wondering,
What is the most efficient subquery that can be written to retrieve the information of the customer stored in the table `customer_info` who has performed the highest amount of purchases in total.(The purchase data is in the table `purchase_logs`). i.e the number of transactions one customer has performed NOT the quantity of the items purchased.
i.e my aim is to retrieve the customer details of the customer witht he highest amount of purchases done.
I have 3 tables one for the `customer_info`, one as the `purchase_logs` and the last one being the `item_info`.

**My current Approach**

```
SELECT * FROM customer_info
WHERE customer_id = (SELECT cust_id
    FROM purchase_logs 
    GROUP BY cust_id
    ORDER BY COUNT(*)
    DESC LIMIT 1);
```

This doesn't seem to give me any results at all unfortunately.

This is my [**Database Schema**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIKky.png)  along with the Sample Data of [**purchase_logs**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRVyX.png), [**customer_info**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYnFD.png), [**item_info**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuwJK.png) and the [**Expected Output**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbY4K.png)

I would really appreciate any help in understanding what the proper approach to solving this problem would be.

Comment: Are you looking for highest amount of purchases or highest number of purchases. Your question has 'highest amount', but the example you show does count(*) ?

Comment: highest number of purchase i.e the number of transactions one customer has performed
not the quantity of the items purchased.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [mre] Please clarify via edits, not comments. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) Google many clear concise precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

There is no `limit 1` in Oracle SQL, use [row limiting clause](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABBADDD) instead (`fetch first` in the example below):

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT cust_id, count(*) cnt
     FROM purchase_logs 
     GROUP BY cust_id
     ORDER BY cnt desc
     fetch first 1 row only with ties
    ) vc
    join customer_info
        on customer_id = vc.cust_id;
```

Comment: This gives me the error that I'm missing a right parenthesis
`     fetch first 1 row only with ties
     *
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` , I've noticed this a few times whenever I try to use order by in a subquery. What should I be doing differently ?

Comment: Without create table statements , test data and expected outcome is difficult for people to help and test. This is the reason images are discouraged as people aren't going to spend time settling up your data. Convert the images to data and people will be amenable to help you solve your problem

Comment: Ah I see, will keep that in mind. thank you